# Connecting Oracle Database to Java Class on server Using JDBC

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I currently have a database that runs on Oracle 11g. My plan is to create a jSwing Application that sends request to a server which allows the database to be modified accordingly. The problem is, the server class will not connect to the database. Below is the preferences for the database as shown in Oracle 11g.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3k5L.png

The code i am using to connect to this database is shown below:-

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:ChrisGraves/<password>@localhost:1521:LettingsAgent";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```

Can anyone see any reason why my database is not getting connected and, if so, how to rectify the problem. Any cooperation is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service name is wrong, instead `LettingsAgent` in the connection string there should be `XE`.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
//notice i don't use the class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
//since that is deprecated class

String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE";

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "ChrisGraves", "<password>"); 
//put the username and password as separate parametars
```

As further reading you can check this [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is incorrect.
Try the following. Note that jvma should be the **servicename** and not **SID**.

jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@//localhost:5521/jvma

Comment: There is nothing wrong `DriverManager.getConnection(URL);` It's not a "very old way" - it's still supported and the only portable way to get a JDBC connection (if you don't want to use JNDI)